# Trouble in html formatted email in php

Tags: php, html

I am sending an approval/disapproval mail to one of the user.In that email i want to show a button so that when the user click the button the request canbe approved or disapproved. But their's a problem coming, I cannot see button in the mail when i receive it. Code is below. 
Please help me.

```
             $to = $email;
             $subject = "Payment Confirmation";
             $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
             $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
             $headers .= "From: $email" . "\r\n" .
            "Reply-To: $email" . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
            $message = '<html><head><!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS - 
           ->
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

     <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head><body>';
     $message .= '<h1 CONFIRMATION EMAIL</h1>';
    $message .= '<p> <?php echo($name) ?> has reuqested payment. Kindly approve or 
                disapprove the requets</p>';
               $message .='<button class="btn btn-success" type="button"> <a 
              href="approveR.php"></a>APPROVE</button>';
             $message .= '</body></html>';

      mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
<?php
$to = $email;
$subject = "Payment Confirmation";
$headers = "From: " . $email . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". $email . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$message = '<html><head><!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

            <!-- Optional theme -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

            <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            </head><body>';
            $message .= '<h1 CONFIRMATION EMAIL</h1>';
            $message .= '<p> '. $name .' has reuqested payment. Kindly approve or 
            disapprove the requets</p>';
            $message .='<button class="btn btn-success" type="button"> <a 
            href="approveR.php"></a>APPROVE</button>';
$message .= '</body></html>';

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: why? try to send `$message = '<h2>hello</h2>';` is it working or not

Comment: i can see the text but button is not showing thats my problem